# Is there a way to view a json file on multiple lines in pycharm?

Tags: python, json, pycharm

My searches for this question have just resulted in finding questions where users ask about multiline strings. My question isn't about this.

Let's say I have a big dictionary saved in a json file. For instance something like this:

`{name1: {attribute1: value1, attribute2: value2, attribute3: value3}, name2: {attribute1: value1, attribute2: value2, attribute3: value3}, name3: {attribute1: value1, attribute2: value2, attribute3: value3}}`

For many people with many attributes, this becomes impossible to read properly if it is all printed on one line, as it is in pycharm. Is there a way to configure pycharm so that it shows this kind of data in a more readable way when I try and read it by opening the file itself? I am aware that I can write a function to pretty print this, or use json.dumps with specifying indent, but I want to know if this is possible in the actual editor. It would ideally look something like this:

```py
{
    name1: {
                attribute1: value1,
                attribute2: value2,
                attribute3: value3
            },
    name2: {
                attribute1: value1,
                attribute2: value2,
                attribute3: value3
            },
    name3: {
                attribute1: value1,
                attribute2: value2,
                attribute3: value3
            }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the Json is in a separate file, you can do Actions -> Reformat code.

[image]

Not sure if there's a way to do it on file opening though.

Comment: Thanks for a solution that does not require a plugin.

Comment: Where did you get that actions window pop up from?

Comment: @Fakipo you should press Shift twice, then choose Actions as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Opening a separate file in the Mac version, it is in the "Code" drop down -> "Reformat Code" or Option-Command-L

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin for PyCharm called `JSON Parser` that gives you this for example:

[image]

To access the plugin just press `Shift` twice and then type `json parser`. Make sure it's `ON`. Also the plugin should be available on one of the tool tabs. See the image.

[image]

In my IDE I have it on the side toolbar. Clicking it, opens the Plugin window.

[image]

Comment: This looks like it does the job! I have gone to settings, plugins and installed it, and restarted the IDE. How do I then actually open and use the plugin as you have done?